# Using bye bug on Heroku

Tags: heroku, byebug

I have a simple Sinatra application. When I launch it (`rackup`) locally, and I place a `byebug` breakpoint, then I can see and interact with bye bug when that spot is reached in the code.

When I deploy that same app on `heroku`, I have problems:

1. Using `heroku logs -t` I can see the output of the server as it runs, and when it hits the break point, I can see it but not interact with it.
2. Using `heroku run irb` I can run an interactive rib session but it is not of the running server.

I think this must be possible but I cannot find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt this is possible. 
When you run "heroku run irb", you are spinning up and interacting with a [Heroku one-off dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos).
The one-off dyno is a completely separate VM, that has no connection (out of the box) with the dyno(s) running your Sinatra app.
You can check on [Heroku Elements](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) to see if there might be add-ons to enable you to debug your running Sinatra app, but out of the box, I don't think you can run an interactive irb session against it.

Comment: So far I came to the same conclusion. But maybe someone has an approach.